# Is it possible to mouse walk in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2, accessibility

I'd like to walk using only my mouse, as I can do in other games like Diablo 3. I searched and didn't find an option for this in Guild Wars 2. Is there no option to do this? Is there a workaround? A left hand handicap makes "W_S_A_D" or arrow keys difficult for directing my avatar.

Comment: Are all your questions going to be essentially "can I click-to-move in [Insert Game Name Here]"?  While I understand it can be useful, especially for those with disabilities, a *lot* of games just aren't designed in such a way that it's practical (if at all possible) to play like that.  I don't know much about Guild Wars, but Skyrim (from your other question) is a prime example of this.

Comment: try [tag:runes-of-magic] you can use the mouse for casual gaming, in the same was as Diablo 3.

Comment: Two questions is hardly enough to complain about a pattern, Iszi.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can.

If you keep holding the <kbd>left button</kbd> of your mouse, you can hold your <kbd>right button</kbd> to make your character walk. Changing the view angle will make your character move to the pointed way.

Tip: You can click <kbd>R</kbd> to enable auto-run.

Comment: Also, doing the inverse (holding right butto and then hold left button also works.

Answer (score 3):

You can't move in exactly the same way, by clicking on the ground, but you can move using the mouse. You can hold right-click and move the mouse to look around, and if you hold right and left click at the same time, you will walk forwards.

This will allow you to move using the mouse, but you will be unable to strafe.

Comment: This is pretty standard in similar games these days, too.  (I really like the way TSW does this where middle-click is mapped to autorun, too)

Answer (score 1):

Holding both right-click and left-click at the same time will cause you to walk forward. This isn't the same thing as click-to-move movement, but it does allow movement to be controlled solely by the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

There are freeware programs which can take a joystick input and translate it to keystrokes. AFAIK one is actually called Joy2Key, but there are others.

One can get a 10$ gamepad with an analog stick and then set up joy2key to translate the stick movement to WASD.

I don't use these programs, but I do use a joy2Midi program to translate joystick buttons to midi inputs for use in a guitar stomp box connected to a virtual amplifier. Similar principle.

Answer (score 1):

With no mouse button pressed or left mouse button pressed:
W and S walk forward and backward,
A and D rotate left and right,
moving mouse only rotates the visual

With right mouse button pressed:
W and S walk the way pointed by mouse,
A and D strafe left and right,
mpving mouse rotates visual and character direction

With left and right mouse buttons pressed:
The character walks forward,
moving mouse rotates visual and character direction
(BTW quite useful when typing while running!)

Answer (score -1):

If you have a mouse with programmable buttons, you can map the walk function to one of these buttons. This should work pretty well.